# Open Source C++ Data Visualization Library

Tags: c++, open-source, visualization

We want to include data visualization in our desktop GUI (mostly timelines and graphs; clickable, draggable). We want to restrict to open-source, non-copyleft C++ libraries that allow commercial use and are portable across many platforms. Which library can I use? Our GUI is based on WxWidgets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/).

And if data visualization is your thing, have a look at [opendx](http://www.opendx.org/highlights.php) too.

Comment: How is that compared to Graphviz?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question would be easier to answer if you also stated which other GUI components you use. Perhaps that limits the choice of available libraries. Since you're C++ and cross-platform, maybe wxWindows? Would be good not to have to guess.